# Запрос api к сервису Soap с помощью Python

Tags: python, xml, request, soap, шаблоны

нужно сделать запрос к сервису с Soap с помощью Python. У сервиса нет нечего для помощи настройки запросов Python
Есть код для запроса php:

````
    'wsdl'    => 'http://api.rossko.ru/service/v2.1/GetSearch',
    'options' => array(
        'connection_timeout' => 1,
        'trace' => true
    )
);

$param = array(
    'KEY1' => 'you_key_1',
    'KEY2' => 'you_key_2',
    'text' => '333114',
    'delivery_id' => '000000002',
    'address_id'  => '112233'
);

$query  = new SoapClient($connect['wsdl'], $connect['options']);
$result = $query->GetSearch($param);

print_r($result);```

Как сделать на Python? Или помогите составить data-template <?xml version="1.0"?>
````

Answer (score 0):

Для SOAP есть библиотеки, можно, например, использовать zeep

```
import zeep  # Надо установить

client = zeep.client.Client('http://api.rossko.ru/service/v2.1/GetSearch')

# Этот принт 'расскажет' о сервисе, я обычно храню его где-то  
# print(client.wsdl.dump())  

# Ну и собственно запрос
print(client.service.GetSearch(
    'you_key_1', 'you_key_2', '333114', '000000002', 112233))
```